# EF AmbigiousMatchException virtual int overwritten with Enum

Tags: entity-framework

i have an interesting problem with EF. All my models inherit from EntityBase

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Id is virtual because on some models i needed to overwrite the Attributes. However, i have now one model that needs an enum as id.

```
internal class Katalog : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public new EKatalog Id { get { return (EKatalog)base.Id; } set { base.Id = (int)value; } }
    ////EKatalog IKatalog.Id => throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    ////public override int Id { get => base.Id; set => base.Id = value; }
}
```

In this constellation i get an AmbigiousMatchException from EF (this comes from Type.GetProperty. If this founds more than one, this exception is thrown).

So i tried to reconfigure the base property in the OnModelCreating

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Types().Where(t => t == typeof(Katalog)).Configure(c =>
            {
                //var properties = c.ClrType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.Name == "Id");
                //PropertyInfo propIdKatalog = c.ClrType.GetProperty("Id", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly); // .Where(p => p.Name == "Id");
                //PropertyInfo propIdBase = c.ClrType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).First(p => p.Name == "Id" & p.DeclaringType == typeof(EntityBase));

                ////propIdBase.CustomAttributes.

                //ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration propConfigBase = c.Property(propIdBase);
                //propConfigBase.HasColumnAnnotation("NotMapped", new NotMappedAttribute());

                //var propConfig = c.Property(propIdKatalog);

                //propConfig.HasColumnOrder(0);
                //propConfig.IsKey();
            });

        ////var converter = new ValueConverter<Katalog>();
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Katalog>().Ignore(x=>x.)

        ////modelBuilder.Entity<Katalog>().Map(m =>
        ////{
        ////    m.MapInheritedProperties().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnAnnotation()
        //})
    }
```

I commented all my ideas out, because nothing really works. What i need is excecially in this type to not map the base id column. In Katalog i need the enum id property.

EDIT 1:
after checking the answer i found out, that the problem occured in the Seed-Method. I had this Seed:

```
    protected override void Seed(EFOverwriteIntEnum.ApplicationContext.DatabaseContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.

        #region Katalogeinträge

        List<Katalog> katalogEntry = new List<Katalog>
        {
            new Katalog
            {
                Id = EKatalog.BeiratWert, Theme = "BeiratWert"
            },
            new Katalog
            {
                Id = EKatalog.BringungWert, Theme = "BringungWert"
            },
        };

        foreach (var entry in katalogEntry)
        {
            // context.Katalog.AddOrUpdate(entry); // AmbigiousMatchException - bug in DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate
            context.Katalog.Add(entry);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I used the AddOrUpdate-Method from the DbSetMigrationsExtensions, as it is recommended in the generated comment. But especially in this case, there is a bug. If i use the normal Add and SaveChanges-Method, it works.

Thanks for the help. I will mark the given answer as answer, because it pointed me to the right direction.

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it to work with EF6, however not with EF Core.

EF6: I used an EntityTypeConfiguration. The key here was I think to avoid the duplicate [Key] declarations. The following worked:

```
    public enum TestIds
    {
        None = 0,
        Sun,
        Moon,
        Earth
    }

   public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        public new TestIds Id { get { return (TestIds)base.Id; } set { base.Id = (int)value; } }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<TestEntity>
    {
        public TestEntityConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("TestEntity");
            HasKey(x => x.Id)
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        }
    }
```

I could access the entities by ID using the enum:

```
[Test]
public void TestByEnum()
{
    using (var context = new TestDbContext())
    {
        var entities = context.TestEntities.ToList();

        var earth = context.TestEntities.Single(x => x.Id == TestIds.Earth);

    }
}
```

The same cannot be said for EFCore. Using `IEntityTypeConfiguration` I couldn't get it to stop complaining about the mismatching type. I tried [NotMapped] on the "new" subclass property, but then it seemed to ignore the Key definition.

Ultimately this would be a case for not extending the base class for this entity type. Base classes are for classes which have *identical* properties & behaviour. As soon as you need to deviate from that, the entity is no longer part of that common set. Typically this is a sign of premature optimization or consistency for consistency's sake. (which I consider anti-patterns) Build it to work, then optimize in patterns to reduce duplication etc. It generally ends up with better code than attempting to write it optimally, then de-optimize or hack around that presumption when things don't fit. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. aktually you're right, your code is working. in my real life i have a foreign key to another table, which is not working. are you able to add a foreign key to test if this works? or should i open a new question for that?

Comment: Just update your question with an appended section outlining the Foreign key that doesn't appear to work. Aim for an example that demonstrates the issue.